# 3 column layout with header and footer in center column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make my page look like the Facebook Android app. The app can be summarized as having a 3 column layout with only the central column having the header (there is no footer, but in my requirement I also need a footer).

This can be shown in the image below

[image]

The red and blue div's are the left and right side-bars. The green and purple div's are the center div. The purple div's are the header and footer div's and would be sticking to the top and bottom of the page respectively.

One more requirement is there will be buttons on the header (top purple) to hide and show the left and right sidebars. Initially only the center div will be visible and the rest can be called into view as and when required. Here is my code till now. (I am not able to get the width for the center div)

**HTML Code**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="leftBar" class="main">Left Bar</div>
    <div id="content" class="inner">
        <div id="header">Head</div>
        <div id="body">Body</div>
        <div id="footer">Footer</div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightBar" class="main">Right Bar</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
margin: 0px;
}

div.inner{
height: 500px;
width: 50%;
background: red;
}

div.main{
background: lime;
height: 200px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

#leftBar{
float: left;
}

#content{
position: relative;
height: 100%;
float: left;
}

#rightBar{
float: right;
}

#header{
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
background: blue;
}

#body{
margin-top: 40px;
position: relative;
}

#footer{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
}
```

I have also added the JavaScript code in the fiddle linked below
http://jsfiddle.net/mv6Bj/1/

The width should be such that the center div is full 100% width of the screen and when the right/left toggles come into the picture they should come to their position and push the center div to the left or right respectively. This is as per the standard Facebook app functionality.

These are the issues I am getting right now

1. The center div is not 100% and neither does it scale as elements appear and disappear
2. The height of the center div is not 100% (it is on Chrome, but strangely it is not on JSFiddle)
3. When I click on left, the leftBar disappears and the content div moves to the left but the header div remains where it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding, I have updated the fiddle.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/mv6Bj/2/)**

I have used `display:table` propery. You can refer [this](http://caniuse.com/css-table) or [this](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display)

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#main {
    min-height:100%;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#leftBar, #rightBar {
    background: lime;
    width:100px;
    display:table-cell;
}

#content {
    min-height: 100%;
    display:table-cell;
    background: red;
}

#header {
    background: blue;
    height:10%;
}
#body {
 min-height:80%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#footer {
 background: magenta;
height:10%;
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Just testing it now and came across a issue, let me know if it can be done. I want the header to fill the width of the content div and also be fixed to the top of the page. Essentially when I scroll down the header div should be always on top.

Answer (score 0):

you can checkout this fiddle i made some changes in your css accordingly.

```
body {
   margin: 0px;
}
div.inner {
   height: 500px;
   width: 50%;
   background: red;
}
div.main {
   background: lime;
   bottom:0px;
   top:0px;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: absolute;
   width:20%;

}
 #leftBar {
 float: left;
}
 #content {
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
 width:60%;
 left:20%;
 float:left;

 }
 #rightBar {
float: right;
width:20%;
 background: lime;
top:0px;
bottom:0px;
left:80%;
    position:absolute;
}
#header {
float: left;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
background: blue;
left:20%;
right:20%;
}
#body {
margin-top: 40px;
position: relative;
}
#footer {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
position: fixed;

margin-left: 0px;
background: blue;
left:20%;
right:20%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mv6Bj/3/